# When I alter the password for a user then try to log out and log in with this password it doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, psql

these are the comands which I had been trying to make work:
CREATE USER Nanana WITH PASSWORD '12345';
\q
Then I try to login to this user with:
psql -U Nanana -h localhost -p 5432
Then it asks for my password, I insert '12345' but I keep getting the error --> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Nanana".
Shouldn't it have worked????

Comment: In `psql `(assuming you can log in as other user) do `\du`. I'm guessing that `Nanana` is actually `nanana` and that you have to log in as `-U nanana`. To preserve case you need to double quote the name, `CREATE USER "Nanana " ...`. For more information read docs [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: It wasn't this. I created it normaly, just the nanana

Comment: Then did `-U nanana` work?

Comment: It's not the login that's the problem, it's the password, it keeps saying that it's wrong, but I'm inserting it just fine

Comment: `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Nanana"` is the error you would get if the user name is actually `nanana` and you did  `-U Nanana` So once again have you tried with `-U nanana`?

Comment: In fact I had done that, but it just said that the login was wrong

Comment: If you want an answer you will need to update your question with 1) The output of `\du` in `psql` 2) The `psql` connection command line you are using. 3) The complete error message you receive.

Comment: OMG I figured it out thank god. I needed to create a database for that. I'm just getting started with using postgresql through the ubuntu command line. Thanks for your help man!